# How to let different Docker containers talk to each other without exposing the ports to the whole world

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I needed to test my `kafka` consumer and message triggers in a controlled environment. So I made an `ansible` project for creating some mock `kafka` servers: [mokafelk](https://github.com/xialingxiao/mokafelk).

It works fine except the security is shit. The `playbook` spins up a 3-node `dockerized` `kafka` cluster by default but the listening ports on the kafka servers are exposed to all. Here's the [`jinja2` template](https://github.com/xialingxiao/mokafelk/blob/master/templates/docker-compose.yml) of the `Dockerfile` used for creating the cluster.

Basically I want the containers to be able to talk to each other. I don't think container linking is an option because it seems to me linking is only one-way. But exposing a port using `127.0.0.1:{{ port }}:{{ port }}` only exposes the port to the hosting machine and does not expose the port to the other containers if I am correct. `0.0.0.0:{{ port }}:{{ port }}` exposes the port to the whole world. So how could I link two+ containers both ways? This must be a common problem but I don't seem to find a quick solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker container networking is explained in detail here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/

In short:

By default docker daemon adds a network adapter docker0 to the host system (it tries to guess an available IP, often uses 172.17.0.1). You can see this in `$ ifconfig`.

All containers are by default connected to this network in incremental IPs. You can examine the containers network settings via `$ docker inspect <container name>`.

So chances are good your docker cluster's IPs are as follows:
kafka1 172.17.0.2
kafka2 172.17.0.3
kafka3 172.17.0.4
elasticsearch 172.17.0.5
kibana 172.17.0.6

You can then access your kafkas at 172.17.0.2:9092, 172.17.0.3:9092, 172.17.0.4:9092 from the host system and from the containers alike.

Comment: thank you mate for the answer i hv never tried this but making the ip address hard coded inside the scripts is bad practice as well no? it also assumes that no other containers r running at the start of play

Comment: Just read the link you posted. I wasn't aware of user defined networks of `docker`. it seems like a new feature. `docker network create --driver bridge isolated_nw` creates a new network and creating all containers inside this user-defined network would allow them to communicate with each other by name automatically, which is not supported in the default bridge network.